# Google Analytics unique events is incorrect

Tags: google-analytics

We have a Google Analytics account set up to track downloads on certain files. When you create a report  with, for example, Event Label (user) as the primary field, and Event Action (file name) as the secondary field, GA will say that the number of unique events is 168. When you add up the numbers in the unique events column, however, they add up to 322. Exporting the table as a CSV file and viewing it in Excel will also give you 322.

I should also add that there are 270 rows in the table, so for there to be 168 unique events, that would mean some user/file combinations would have 0 unique events, which doesn't make any sense.

Can anybody shed some light on why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of confusion with *Unique Events* metric. Instead of counting a number of times an event with unique combination of category/action/label happened, GA was counting unique combination of every **dimension** included in the report! 
Finally that metric is deprecated now and renamed to **Unique Events (legacy)**.
Instead we get a real **Unique Events (new)** metric which behave like expected.

More explanation in my blog post
http://www.internetrix.com.au/blog/google-analytics-unique-events-are-dead-long-live-unique-events/

Answer (score 0):

In all Google Analytics custom reports, the Unique Events field actually reports the number of Visits (or sometimes a slightly higher number).

Built-in Google Analytics reports will show you the correct number of Unique Events.

It's a bug, plain and simple. I reported it to Google [back in August](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/analytics/ZEiluoGkg3U), but it's still broken.

Answer (score 0):

The number in the Google Analytics standard reports can be explained...but as Aaron pointed out, it sure looks broken.  I wrote an article explaining it all: 
http://www.analyticsedge.com/2014/09/misunderstood-metrics-unique-events/