# Why does ga:users metric affect ga:uniqueEvents count?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, universal-analytics

I use this query to get data from Google Analytics: http://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/?dimensions=ga%253AnthDay%252Cga%253AeventCategory&metrics=ga%253AtotalEvents%252Cga%253AuniqueEvents%252Cga%253Ausers&filters=ga%253AeventCategory%253D%253DsomeCategory%253Bga%253AeventLabel%253D%253D0&start-date=2014-09-11&end-date=2014-09-25&max-results=50

The strange thing is that ga:users metric affects the result value of ga:uniqueEvents metric.

The query without ga:users produces the following results:
[image: Results without ga:users]

The query with ga:users produces the following results:
[image: Results with ga:users]

If I include ga:eventAction dimension to the query - results becomes independent from ga:users metric.

Why does it happen? In my understanding metrics should not affect each other in reporting queries.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18788066/google-analytics-unique-events-is-incorrect, guess you have stumbled on a known bug